# put works in postman but not google scripts

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to push sheets data from a quiz to an api.  The put works fine in postman but I can't seem to get it to work in google scripts.

Postman

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic bmljazpuaWNr");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "FB_ResponseHeaders=%7b%22X-XSS-Protection%22%3a%7b%22Key%22%3a%221%3b+mode%3dblock%22%2c%22Value%22%3a%225C-58-58-82-DB-E9-4D-AD-BF-23-F8-5A-65-1E-EE-7B-96-94-7C-E6%22%7d%2c%22X-Content-Type-Options%22%3a%7b%22Key%22%3a%22nosniff%22%2c%22Value%22%3a%22E9-85-E8-2B-38-74-3B-AA-71-5A-41-1D-65-49-06-A7-FF-B3-D2-57%22%7d%2c%22Strict-Transport-Security%22%3a%7b%22Key%22%3a%22max-age%3d31536000%3b+includeSubDomains%22%2c%22Value%22%3a%221D-31-04-88-80-8A-6A-27-8E-2D-72-C5-32-98-74-A9-F8-E8-0C-E7%22%7d%7d; fbd_cooked=!/muNNuj9SlbMhC0PporV/qqu1cgGGvczJaMywTIzq+9GDRYedxCjdCU9X3WnSt1ijLXqndrZJ1DCTVw=");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "fieldName": "SingleLineText5",
  "fieldValue": "question1test"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

Google Scripts

```
  // put em in a payload
var payload = {  
  "fieldName": "SingleLineText7",
  "fieldValue": "question1googleSheet" }
var encodedAuth = Utilities.base64Encode("nick:nick");
var headers = [{"Authorization" : "Basic " + encodedAuth},{"Content-Type":"application/json"}];
var options = {
  'method': 'PUT',
  'body': JSON.stringify(payload),
  'headers': headers,
  'redirect': 'follow'
}

response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);



//log the response
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Am receiving
Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: headers

If i remove the "Content-Type" I get no error but send no data just returns {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)) you are using the wrong parameter. It should be:

```
const options = {
  method : "PUT", // this was correct
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload), // correct this 
  followRedirects : true, // correct this
  headers: headers
}
```

Comment: That plus changing headers to  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + encodedAuth, "Content-Type":"application/json"};